# Acrescentar ou reduzir um valor no .top ao clicar no link para ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Tenho uma função em jQuery que faz um Scroll suave na página, ao clicar no link do ID.

```js
$(function() {
  $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
  if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
   var target = $(this.hash);
   target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
   if (target.length) {
    $('html, body').animate({
     scrollTop: target.offset().top
    }, 1000);
    return false;
   }
  }
  });
 });
```

Ela funciona perfeitamente. O problema, é que eu tenho uma div com position fixed de `height: 100px` que da um overlay nos primeiros 100px da div. Preciso acrescentar esses 100px na hora que acontecer o Scroll, clicando na div. Não faço ideia de como fazer isso.

Comment: Eu não entendi muito bem o que você precisa, exemplifique melhor. Se for o caso, poste seu HTML e CSS também. Teu código acima, ao executar está dando erro, é possível colocá-lo em um JSFiddle, JSBin ou CodePen?

Comment: Na onde tem scrollTop você coloca menos 100. Ficaria assim scrollTop: (target.offset().top - 100)

Comment: @HugoLima Perfeito! Não sabia que podia representar dessa forma. Obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

var targetOffset = $target.offset().top - 100;

Ou pegue a altura do elemento de cabeçalho para o deslocamento extra.

var targetOffset = $target.offset().top - $("element").outerHeight(true);